# I can't use my sprint key while I jump in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I remember when I was on my Windows 8 laptop, I could press my sprint key, which is Caps Lock (don't judge) and I could hold it while I jump, but on my new Windows 10 computer, I can't hold my sprint key and jump. Are there any suggestions to fix this please?

Comment: Perhaps Caps + Space may be a key sequence that Windows intercepts before passing it along to the game. Does Caps + Space do anything when not inside minecraft?

Comment: No it doesnt, when i hold caps, my sprint key, and try to jump it wont, i would have to let go of my sprint key to jump

Comment: Is there any option restricting pressing two keys at once at all?

Answer (score 0):

You said swapped from your laptop to a new computer, which means you have a new keyboard as well. It's possible that this new keyboard cannot do these two buttons presses at the same time due to *keyboard ghosting*. As detailed in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/304147/145980), many typical keyboard are wired in such a way that certain key combinations can't be registered. The affected key combos vary depending on which keyboard you're using. The only way to get around this limitation is to get an anti-ghosting keyboard.